# Installshield Targetdir

Tags: installshield

I'am trying to make a small installer. Basic MSI.

The installdir should be \ProgramFiles\some & some\

But when I execute the installer, the "&" can't be seen. But it seems to choose the right folder. It is installed ok, to the right folder. How can I make the "&" visible in the path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting, I've never come across this problem before.  The short answer is this is a side effect of using a Text control on the Custom Setup Dialog.  If you press the browse button you'll see it is correct it's just getting formatted wierd.   The work around would be to replace the text control with an edit control.  Just be sure to give it the same subscription of SelectionPath : Text  so that it displays data.  Consider also setting enabled to false and sunken to false.  Also be sure to not mess up the tab order.

BTW, I'd reccomend against installing to  '&' anyways.  It's a special character in DOS and makes navigating to the directory from a command line a pain.

Comment: ok, but I dont know how to replace the text control with an edit control. I thought that it wouldnt be possible since I use a "template" from Installshield

Comment: You don't mention what version or edition of InstallShield you have but basically you go into the dialog edit and delete one control then drag on the new control and wire it up.

Comment: I use installshield 2010. But I have just started to use it, so I'am quit new to it